# derby database with 2 linked tables

Tags: design-patterns

I'm working on a photo collection app, coded in java and using derby for storage. The idea is that there will be a file system view of the collection and also a category based view. Each photo will be in one or more (probably less than 5) categories and each category might hold hundreds of photos.

So I've come up with ideas for my tables:-

**photo**

```
id INT(5000)    
file_path TINYTEXT(100) 
categories foreign key(s)
```

**category**

```
id TINYINT(50) 
name    TINYTEXT(30)
photos foreign key(s)
```

But how to allow each photo id several categories and each category id many photos? What's the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for what is called a many-to-many relationship. This is not the most common relationship type however it is common enough that there are plenty of examples of best practice. What you would do is create a third database table and call it something like photocategoryrelations. In that table you would have entries (rows) representative of the relations between the two tables. This kind of table is typically called a junction table, bridging table, or linking table. The terminology is interchangeable. The bridging table's columns should include the unique ids from both the participating tables (photos, and categories). These could then be used as foreign keys.

[Here's a quick article describing a couple different database relationship types including the many-to-many relationship that you will need.](https://medium.com/@emekadc/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-when-designing-a-database-9da2de684710)

Edit: In a lot of cases, the relationship table itself can in fact be representative of something more concrete and you can name it as such. For instance a lot of examples out there for this scenario use classes and students for their participating tables and the bridging table is called enrollments because it represents all of the class enrollments. A class can have multiple students, and students can be in multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks TheFunk - that was very helpful. It's difficult to find information about something if you don't know what  it's called. I've managed to work out the SQL for all the crud operations, so I'm all go now.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck to you and good first question. Once your bridging table is set up, you'll just need separate queries with where clauses related to the subject matter of the page. So if you're in the categories view, you'd `select from pcrs where categoryID = X` and the where just changes between views. So in photo view you'd do `where photoID = Y`.